# Get 'spawn cmd ENOENT' when try to build Cordova application (event.js:85)

Tags: node.js, cordova, cmd, spawn

Get this error in windows cmd when I try to build (emulate) Cordova app.

```
D:\dev\Cordova\toDoList>cordova build android

Running command: D:\dev\Cordova\toDoList\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat
events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1046:32)
at child_process.js:1137:20
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: D:\dev\Cordova\toDoList\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I checked system variables one more time and found the cause of the problem:
missing `C:\Windows\System32\` variable.
I added it and that solved my problem

Hope, it help you too.

Comment: Did you add it to the path? Or did you create a new variable?

Answer (score 20):

just add it to the PATH: C:\Windows\System32 and start cmd as Administrator

Answer (score 10):

Goto > Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advance system setting\Enviroment variable and set system variables path `C:\Windows\System32\` variable and restart your System.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old but I simply had to run Visual Studio 2015 as an administrator and it worked on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

I know its too late to answer, but incase if someone ran into trouble again.
I tried the solutions above which tells to add System32 path, But in my case the cordova path was deleted by an accident.
So I added `C:\Users\Aquib\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin` to environment variable path and it worked !