# Yeoman - Gulp spawn cmd enoent

Tags: node.js, windows, gulp, yeoman, yeoman-generator

With the help gulp yeoman-webapp 'im wolf. But it also serves on the command line, I get the following error gulp. Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

I work in Windows 10 and 64 bit computing.

> events.js:85
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>               ^
>   Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
>       at child_process.js:1144:20
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

Comment: When it comes to server error occurred gulp run. I also founded yeoman gulp-webapp.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624686/get-spawn-cmd-enoent-when-try-to-build-cordova-application-event-js85

Answer (score 0):

Try to put in your system variables in the PATH : 
C:\Windows\System32;