# Yeoman/Gulp throwing 'spawn gulp ENOENT' error on a Mac

Tags: angularjs, macos, npm, gulp, yeoman-generator

**Please note:** I *do* see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624686/get-spawn-cmd-enoent-when-try-to-build-cordova-application-event-js85) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226473/yeoman-gulp-spawn-cmd-enoent) but those were **both instances where the developer was on Windows**, and the solution was Windows-specific. **I am on a Mac!** Please don't closevote as a duplicate!!!

---

Mac 10.12.6 here. I'm new to AngularJS (v1.x) and am trying to follow this [tutorial on using Yeoman to create an internationalized AngularJS app](https://scotch.io/tutorials/internationalization-of-angularjs-applications).

I install the Yeoman AngularJS generator and create a directory for my simple/test app:

```
npm install -g generator-angular
mkdir angular-translate-yeoman && cd $_
```

Then I go to create my internationalization AngularJS app:

```
yo angular translate
```

It asks me a bunch of questions, **I select `gulp` instead of `grunt`**, and then starts generating the scaffolding. About a minute later I get the following error:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn gulp ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

**Anybody have any idea what the problem is and what the fix is?**

Comment: Please add your npm, node, gulp, yo and generator-gulp-angular versions. Thanks

Comment: Your question prompted me to find the answer myself, thanks @lin (+1). Gulp wasn't installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm leaving this question up rather than deleting it. The problem was that I didn't have gulp installed, and the tutorial I was using never bothered to mentioned installing gulp as a pre-requisite. Not knowing *anything* about Yeoman, I guess I figured it would install any JS dependencies for me.

So this is the error you'll receive when you're on a Mac and using Yeoman + Gulp together, but Gulp isn't installed on your machine. [To install Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/):

```
npm install gulp-cli -g
npm install gulp -D
touch gulpfile.js
gulp --help
```