# Unable to build ionic tool for android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to install the ionic framework for android using this link http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

I was able to install ionic and add the android platform. However I am getting an error on trying to use the command

```
ionic build android
```

The error I am getting is as below

```
C:\Users\Nachiketh\Devlopment\Ionic\myApp>ionic build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\Nachiketh\Devlopment\Ionic\myApp\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\Nachiketh\Devlopment\Ionic\myApp
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Nachiketh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
```

I have set the path for the ANDROID_HOME in the environment variables. I did try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626189/4761773 but the issue still remains.