# "Error ; spawn cmd ENOENT" in ionic (ionic build android command)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, command

I am building an app using ionic framework.
when I execute the command 'ionic build android' it is showing the following message.

```
C:\Windows\System32\todo>ionic build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Windows\System32\todo\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Windows\System32\todo
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_66

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
```

I am running it on a windows 7 system using node.js command prompt

I have googled, but couldn't find any helpful solution.
Plese help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624686/get-spawn-cmd-enoent-when-try-to-build-cordova-application-event-js85

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be due to your are not set current path of npm(C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm) in environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

On some systems, it was the problem of access:

```
Android Studio 3.0 removes the execute permission from Gradle, breaking the build
```

you can change the permissions and check the result!

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may come from windows services. Windows child process services not running properly.
In windows, OS => Go to System Config and enable all services and restart the computer. For more details [check here](https://helperscript.com/spawn-eperm-at-childprocess-spawn-internal-child_process-js40711-at-object-spawn-child_process-js5539/).