# Can't 'npm start' my React project

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am working on a React.js project for more than 2 weeks. Yesterday, I accidentally changed my PATH variable in environment variable settings. I couldn't run npm after that. But I have set the environment variable again. The problem I am facing now is that I can't 'npm start' my project. It throws an error. I could do it till yesterday. And apart from that I can run all other projects by using this command. The problem is only in running this current project. I know it would seem a duplicate question to many but I have researched and couldn't find the solution.

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28626189/4205611 try this solution

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much! :) Was going through so much pain trying different ways to fix it.