# I am trying to to install Angular and getting error like Spawn cmd ENOET

Tags: angular, npm

I'm setting up Angular in my computer and getting an error like:

> spawn cmd ENOENT

The full stack trace:

```
events.js:136
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:999:13)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:201:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:389:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! metronic-angular@6.0.0 start: `ng serve --open`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the metronic-angular@6.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-09T07_17_18_068Z-debug.log
```

I already change my system path and run as admin still I am getting this error or is there anything I am missing with `npm install`
I try to open `localhost:http://localhost:4200/` but it's show that 
This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get 'spawn cmd ENOENT' when try to build Cordova application (event.js:85)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624686/get-spawn-cmd-enoent-when-try-to-build-cordova-application-event-js85)

Comment: How did you set up your angular project ? Did you created the project with Angular CLI ? took it from somewhere ? What NodeJS / NPM / Angular version do you use ? You have to do a `npm install -g @angular/cli` before getting started.