# Error when I try run a React App with npm start command

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I create a new React Project and I try to start it with the command `npm start` but I have this error:

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! primera-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the primera-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Felipe\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-11T15_55_25_058Z-debug.log
```

I try a lot of things but nothing works.

Comment: Did you create the project using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows about two months ago. I solved it downgrading `react-scripts` to the version `2.1.8`. To do so:

1. Delete `node_modules` directory.
2. Edit `package.json` file to downgrade `react-scripts`. It should look like this: `"react-scripts": "2.1.8"`.
3. Go to the project folder: `cd my-app`.
4. Run `npm install`.
5. Run `npm start`.

If this doesn't work, please check your system variables on Windows and make sure `C:\Windows\System32\` variable is set as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624686/get-spawn-cmd-enoent-when-try-to-build-cordova-application-event-js85) or [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6908#issuecomment-495064048).