# I have problem while running npm start command in cmd in windows 10

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm-start

I am new to React, please help me to solve this error, this screen shows when I try to run the command npm start after react the react project.

[image]

Comment: you can follow the threads here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5980 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when I try run a React App with npm start command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57451701/error-when-i-try-run-a-react-app-with-npm-start-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not because of Reactjs it's because your system doesn't know the path to your system32.
Please follow the below instruction to fix this

> Goto > Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advance system
>   setting\Enviroment variable and set system variables path
>   C:\Windows\System32\ variable and restart your System.

One more options is to downgrade your react-scripts in the packge.json to 2.1.8=> keep this as your last option.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Goto > Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advance system setting\Enviroment variable and set system variables path C:\Windows\System32\ variable and restart your System.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade the `react-scripts` module to version 2.1.8 instead of 3

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following steps:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

delete `node_modules` folder and delete `package-lock.json` file

```
 npm install
```