# Error in "npm start" for newly created project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

I just created a react js project. Then I run "npm start" for run the project. this error come and I am stuck here for 1 day now. I have already have other reactJS projects. This error came for all other projects. That's why I tried it with new project. So I confirmed by creating new project. Error is not in my project.

I already tried.

- Delete node_module folder then npm install
- clear node cache.
- Reinstall node.js
- Create new project.
- Reduce the version of 'react-script'
- Uninstall node.js and delete all files in c drive with the name of "node"
- Installing old version of node.js

Error is,

```
C:\Suranga\ReactJS\JMSL\my_app>npm start

> my_app@0.1.0 start C:\Suranga\ReactJS\JMSL\my_app
> react-scripts start
> Starting the development server...
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my_app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my_app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-10T15_10_01_727Z-debug.log
C:\Suranga\ReactJS\JMSL\my_app>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in https://codesandbox.io ?

Comment: `events.js:174` What are the contents of this file?

Comment: Does this [CRA github issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6985) help?

Comment: Check your environment variable PATH.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626189/12030751

Comment: @Rash I couldn't find the file.

Comment: @It'sNotMe Thank you. I got a solution from this link. I run "npm install react-scripts@2.1.8" and npm start. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For archive purposes, here is [the solution](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6985) reported by OP.

**Downgrade to react-scripts 2.1.8.**

```
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are in the right application folder that was created with create-react-app. Else, trying running `npm install` in the folder.

Comment: Yep I am working on the correct folder. thank you for your ansfer

Answer (score 0):

Still had same problem for others. Previous solution is not success for those projects. finally I did it with following steps.

1) Install Chocolatey for windows (https://chocolatey.org/)

2) Install npm by using choco ("**choco install nodejs-latest**")

3) npm start