# React start npm doesn't work - error event occured

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

I'm trying to start a new react environment using npx command. 
While the npx is working and the directory is formed, when I try to start it won't work (using npm start). 
This is the error I'm getting:

Here's a snapshot of the error I'm receiving:

[image: error:]

Any idea what I need to do?

I've tried to re-install node.js to its latest version and try to change minor things in the package.js file.

Comment: Can you share output of logs (last line shows the path)

Comment: Did your `npm install` completed successfully? if not try running `npm install` again.

Comment: You may need to [downgrade react scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57875296/8943092).