# react-script error while starting the project

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

I created a `reactjs` project using the command `npx create-react-app project-name` and hit the command `npm start` and finally I got the below error not able to resolve

```
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)←[39m
←[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)←[39m
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)←[39m
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)←[39m
←[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)←[39m
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)←[39m {
  errno: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
  code: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
  syscall: ←[32m'spawn cmd'←[39m,
  path: ←[32m'cmd'←[39m,
  spawnargs: [ ←[32m'/c'←[39m, ←[32m'start'←[39m, ←[32m'""'←[39m, ←[32m'/b'←[39m, ←[32m'http://localhost:3000/'←[39m ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sample-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sample-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\My Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-16T05_08_04_473Z-debug.log
```

Initially, I use to create react project at that time there was no problem but recently it started throwing the same error whenever i create the project

Comment: Try to run `npm install` again, it'll resolve your issue. Before running this, remove your current node_modules folder. [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39960890/6630837)

Comment: Your problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626189/1517029) try it

Comment: @The_ehT i have added that environment variable but still error is shown

Comment: @SudheeshR i have updated my node and removed the node modules and installed it again but still the error is shown

Comment: did u open the cmd with administrive privilege?

Comment: @The_ehT yes I have opened cmd as an admin

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the npm cache
npm cache clean --force

And then do an npm install again.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command once

```
npm install react-scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

try reinstalling node.js. Sometimes it works.

Comment: Hi Nourish, just a general code of conduct. For a short suggestion, it is better to do it on the comment section